# Form validation - How to keep track of multiple fields to prevent submit - Global variable?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I have a form with multiple fields (lets say 4 for this example).

I am using javascript functions on each field to validate them, generating an error indication - a red box, or a hint as text next to the box.

like so ..

```
<input
    ...
    onkeyup="validateName()"
    onblur="checkDuplicateName(); validateName()"
>
```

So what I would like to do is not allow a submit if any of the fields do not validate.

So the question is - what is the best way to set it up so submit is disabled unless all 4 fields are valid?

I will use either

```
document.getElementById("mySubmit").disabled=true;
```

or

```
event.preventDefault()
```

(..though trying to avoid Jquery) to prevent the submit.

How should I keep track of the condition of the 4 fields?

Should I create a global variable like - window.validFields, so I can access it from each of my validation functions - adding one to the variable for each field that is valid, and subtracting one when invalid? (window.validFields==4 allows a submit)

Not sure the best way to accomplish this.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a form like this …

```
<form class="is-invalid" id="form" method="post">
  <input type="text" id="lorem">
  <input type="text" id="ipsum">
  <input type="text" id="dolor">
  <input type="text" id="amet">
  <button id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

… you could do the following …

```
(function () {

  var fields = {
        lorem: false,
        ipsum: false,
        dolor: false,
        amet: false
      },
      isValid = false,
      form = document.getElementById('form'),
      i,
      tmpInput;

  // Binding submit-event to prevent form-submit
  form.addEventListener('submit', onSubmit, false);

  // Binding events on input-elements (keyup & blur)
  for ( i in fields ) {
    tmpInput = document.getElementById(i);
    tmpInput.addEventListener('keyup', checkInput, false);
    tmpInput.addEventListener('blur', checkInput, false);
  }

  // Checking form state by iterating over the fields object;
  // Adding/removing 'is-valid'-class and setting `isValid`-flag
  function checkFormState() {
    for ( var j in fields ) {
      if ( !fields[j] ) {
        isValid = false;
        form.className += /\bis-invalid\b/i.test(form.className)
          ? ''
          : 'is-invalid';
        return;
      }
    }
    form.className = form.className.replace(/\bis-invalid\b/i, '');
    isValid = true;
  }

  // Abort the submit, if the `isValid`-flag is `false`
  function onSubmit(evnt) {
    if ( !isValid ) {
      evnt.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  }

  // Setting the corresponding value in the `fields`-object;
  // Checking the form state
  function checkInput() {
    fields[this.id] = this.value.length > 5; // or any other validation rule
    checkFormState();
  }

})();
```

There's an object with the IDs of the relevant input-fields that holds each validation state. On `keyup` and `blur` each input field is checked. If it passes the validation, the corresponding value in the `fields`-object is set to `true`. Additionally the state of the form is checked on each event on an input element.

The `checkState`-function iterates over the `fields`-object. If it finds a property, that is `false`, the 'is-invalid'-class is set on the form-element (if it isn't already set), the `isValid`-flag is set to `false` and the function is aborted.

Otherwise — all input-fields are valid —, the `isValid`-flag is set to true and the 'is-invalid'-class is removed from the form-element. Now, the form can be submitted.

This all works without a single global variable. Mission accomplished!

I made a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vPsK6/2/) where you can test this.

PS: Have in mind, that the `addEventListener`-method is only supported by IEs down to version 9. If you have to support version 8 and below, you need a [workaround like this](http://rubayathasan.com/tutorial/ie8-addeventlistener-alternative-example/).

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Still trying to understand the code. Working too many hours this week.. Just wanting to express my appreciation for your help.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. This one example taught me many things. I implemented this except without using a for-in loop to bind js functions to events. I also left out anything having to do with changing class names since that was not required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the forms submit event, like this:

**HTML**:

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="return MyValidation(); " ...
```

**JS**:

```
(function() {
    var field1Valid = false;
    var field2Valid = false;

    window.validateField1 = function(elmnt) {
        // do some validation...

        if(everything == OK) {
            field1Valid = true;
            setButtonDisabled(false);
        }
        else {
            field1Valid = false;
            setButtonDisabled(true);
        }
    }

    window.validateField2 = function(elmnt) {
        // do some validation...

        if(everything == OK) {
            field2Valid = true;
            setButtonDisabled(false);
        }
        else {
            field2Valid = false;
            setButtonDisabled(true);
        }
    }

    window.checkDuplicateName = function() {
        // do some more validation...
    }

    window.setButtonDisabled = function(disabled) {
        document.getElementById('submit').disabled = disabled;
    }

    window.MyValidation = function() {
        return field1Valid  && field2Valid;
    }
}());
```

The above example also checks whether to disable the submit button or not.

Another way would be to handle all your validation logic within the form submit event, but validating input immediately is always nicer.

There are also quite some validation plugins available for use with jQuery, if you're interested. Building this yourself can get messy quickly if you have multiple fields that need to be validated in multiple ways...

Comment: I thought global variables were bad practice, which is why I asked this question. I guess it seems there is no other way. Also, I was trying to avoid Jquery, which I have so far, but it seems inevitable that I will end up using it, eventually. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: If you're uncomfortable with using global variables, you can use a different setup as I've displayed above....

Comment: Don't forget you can also use HTML5 validation on some elements.

Comment: @nOrakat: If you want to avoid global variables you should omit inline-event-handler, as they pollute the global namespace as well.

Comment: Hi, everyone, thanks for the help. I am still trying to understand many of these new concepts to comment or choose an answer; will get back to it if anyone is still around.

Comment: @Michael Dunn if I got rid of the inline event handlers and registered them traditionally (element.onblur=function) in separate js, then can I just take the original version Reinder Wit gave (or something like it), and enclose it into a self-executing anonymous function? (which should not add anything into the global namespace like the window.function above?) Sorry for slow replies.. working full time non-programming job.

Comment: @nOrakat, I think your question is intended for Reinder Wit (I just did a little bit of editing)